# Applying a file diff to a new file

Tags: python, version-control, text-processing

Suppose I have file `a.txt`, `b.txt` and `c.txt`:

`a.txt`:

```
Hello, I like cake.
```

`b.txt`:

```
Hello, I like turtles.
```

`c.txt`:

```
go away, I don't like you
```

I suspect the difference between `a.txt` and `b.txt` is quantifiable. For example, one could say that characters 15-18 are deleted, and the string `turtles` is inserted.

Now, I would like to calculate this change and then apply it to `c.txt`, which would result in:

```
go away, I donturtlesike you
```

I believe `git` uses an analogous approach to track changes in a repository, apply stashes and so forth. I am looking for something with that level of generality. What is this called in software engineering?

Comment: I don't know if this has a specific name, but I think what you are looking for can be done with Pythons [difflib](https://docs.python.org/2/library/difflib.html#difflib.ndiff). This library can used to detect differences between lists of strings and you could process them in the way you are describing.

Comment: I looked into difflib  but it dorsnt look like applying changes to a new file is possible

Comment: While there isn't a function to directly apply the diffs to a new file, I don't think it would be too difficult to make one that processes the diffs produced by this library.

Comment: "one could say that characters 15-18 are deleted, and the string turtles is inserted" - one could also say that the characters 15-17 are deleted, the string `turtl` is added before the (original) character 18, and the string `s` is added after the (original) character 18. Which is correct?

Comment: All of them. But for each given methodology or algorithm, the assumptions would remain consistent .

Answer (score 2):

> I believe git uses an analogous approach to track changes in a repository, apply stashes and so forth

Misbelieving detected. Git (and all other VCSes) operates with objects "whole string" (with context around it), not separate chars or words inside strings.
In short: diff between `a.txt` and `b.txt` is:

- **String** "Hello, I like cake." deleted
- **String** "Hello, I like turtles." added

Comment: Oh that's good to know... but this is more of a comment rather than an answer. I'm still quite sure it should be possible to quantify the diff in the way I originally stated. Perhaps that's not quite what `git` does, but then I'm not limited to `git` here

Comment: Mhh, not so sure. Git has various options to display diffs, some with context, some without. Git supports various merge algorithms, these all must consider context by nature. Git's internal data model sometimes uses diff algorithms for delta compression, but these don't have to consider context as the base file is always known. (A Git commit should be understood as a snapshot of your project state, not as a description of a change).